# How to encrypt / decrypt AES with Libsodium-PHP

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, libsodium

I need to encrypt/decrypt data with PHP. I am completely new to this, however I have read that Libsodium-PHP is the best tool for AES encryption. Much like the other PHP encryption libraries I have researched Libsoduim-PHP seemed to offer almost no documentation of how to use the library (that I was able to find). Can anyone that has experience with PHP encryption either point me in the direction of a good learning resource or write a few lines of sample code using Libsoduim-PHP?
Thank you very much for the help,
Atlas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Much like the other PHP encryption libraries I have researched Libsoduim-PHP seemed to offer almost no documentation of how to use the library (that I was able to find).

From [the libsodium-php Github page](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) you will find a direct link to [a free online *book*](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium) that covers everything you need to know to get started with libsodium.

The final chapter contains [libsodium recipes](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/09-recipes.md), but each chapter contains detailed usage information.

If you specifically need AES, [read this](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/08-advanced.md#crypto-aead-aes256gcm).

If you don't have an "AES-or-bust" requirement hanging over your head, where failure to specifically use AES means your department gets axed and your developers face a firing squad, you should consider just using [crypto_secretbox](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/05-publickey-crypto.md#crypto-box) which uses Xsalsa20 for encryption and attaches a Poly1305 authentication tag. (This is [authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly), which you want to use almost always.)

Also look into [Halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite) if you want easy-mode.

Comment: sir Scott can you help me on this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587528/cant-decrypt-encrypted-file-using-libsodium

Answer (score 9):

### PHP Version >= 7.2

If you are using PHP >= 7.2 use inbuilt sodium core extension instead.

Sample implementation

```
<?php 
//Simple Usage

/**
* Encrypt a message
* 
* @param string $message - message to encrypt
* @param string $key - encryption key
* @return string
*/
function safeEncrypt($message, $key)
{
    $nonce = random_bytes(
        SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES
    );

    $cipher = base64_encode(
        $nonce.
        sodium_crypto_secretbox(
            $message,
            $nonce,
            $key
        )
    );
    sodium_memzero($message);
    sodium_memzero($key);
    return $cipher;
}

/**
* Decrypt a message
* 
* @param string $encrypted - message encrypted with safeEncrypt()
* @param string $key - encryption key
* @return string
*/
function safeDecrypt($encrypted, $key)
{   
    $decoded = base64_decode($encrypted);
    if ($decoded === false) {
        throw new Exception('Scream bloody murder, the encoding failed');
    }
    if (mb_strlen($decoded, '8bit') < (SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES + SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_MACBYTES)) {
        throw new Exception('Scream bloody murder, the message was truncated');
    }
    $nonce = mb_substr($decoded, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES, '8bit');
    $ciphertext = mb_substr($decoded, SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES, null, '8bit');

    $plain = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open(
        $ciphertext,
        $nonce,
        $key
    );
    if ($plain === false) {
         throw new Exception('the message was tampered with in transit');
    }
    sodium_memzero($ciphertext);
    sodium_memzero($key);
    return $plain;
}
//Encrypt & Decrypt your message
$key = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);

$enc = safeEncrypt('Encrypt This String...', $key); //generates random  encrypted string (Base64 related)
echo $enc;
echo '<br>';
$dec = safeDecrypt($enc, $key); //decrypts encoded string generated via safeEncrypt function 
echo $dec;
```

Comment: I'm running PHP Version 7.2.14. Do you know how I can resolve this error when running your code?
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sodium_crypto_secretbox_keygen()

Comment: @TimM Try $key = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);