# Convert Java AES encryption to PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography

I have a requirement to use AES encryption with specific parameters but the only example provided is in Java. I need to move everything to PHP and I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

In Java the encryption class takes the iv/salt parameters as an array of bytes directly. Something in the likes of:

```
byte[] iv = {(byte) 0xCB, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x1A, (byte) 0xF7, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x8E, (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xC7};

AlgorithmParameterSpec params = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
```

but PHP expects a string for input, so I tried to do something like:

```
private $salt = ['a7', '70', '1f', 'f6', '5e', 'd3', '29', '8f'];
private $iv = ['cb', '35', 'f1', '52', '1b', 'f7', '33', '0b', '75', '03', '8e', 'e0', 'cf', '39', '98', 'c7'];


    public function __construct()
{

    $iv = implode(array_map("hex2bin", $this->iv));
    $this->iv = $iv;

    $salt = implode(array_map("hex2bin", $this->salt));
    $this->salt = $salt;

}

public function encrypt($unencryptedString)
{

    $key = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $this->passPhrase, $this->salt, $this->iterationCount, $this->keyLen, true);
    var_dump($key);
    $hash = openssl_encrypt($unencryptedString, 'AES-128-CBC', $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->iv);

    $encoded = base64_encode($hash);

    return $encoded;

}
```

I imagine I'm not using the iv/salt parameters the same way its used on Java, thats why it doesn't produce the same thing. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Basics (You did good!)

You should always Use a standard library for PHP encryption.

I know we shouldn't be making recommendations but encryption is in my opinion somewhat of an exception and you should utilise tried and tested libraries.

Use either the [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) extensions or [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aes-256-gcm.html)

Answers on using both are linked here.

[How to encrypt plaintext with AES-256 CBC in PHP using openssl()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871579/how-to-encrypt-plaintext-with-aes-256-cbc-in-php-using-openssl/34871988#34871988)

[How to encrypt / decrypt AES with Libsodium-PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477643/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-aes-with-libsodium-php)

#### Problems?

In terms of your implemtation I think the `$iv` and `$key` aren't well formed inputs for `hex2bin()`

```
$iv = ['0xA7', '0x71', '0x1F', '0xF5', '0x5D', '0xD2', '0x28', '0x8F'];
array_map("hex2bin", $iv);

// outputs Warning: hex2bin(): Input string must be hexadecimal string
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the feedback. I'm using openssl extension already, just not sure how to feed the parameters correctly... These examples use random keys as example.

Comment: thanks for the update, its a good starting point. I updated the iv/salt values to have everything in lowercase.

Comment: I can find the matches for hex values in here: http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/203/en but PHP keeps showing the same error, any idea?

Comment: the `0xA7` i believe should just be `00A7` - I think the `0x` notation is to let humans know the encoding is he`x`

Answer (score 0):

Following @Luke's suggestion:

Removing 0x and using lower case in all iv/salt values seems to do it.

```
private $salt = ['a7', '71', '1f', 'f5', '5d', 'd2', '28', '8f'];
```