# Can't decrypt encrypted file using libsodium

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, libsodium

I'm working on the encryption using libsodium my problem is the decryption part, its not going through and displaying error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SodiumException: ops limit must be greater than
>   0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypter\decrypt.php:18 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypter\decrypt.php(18): sodium_crypto_pwhash() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypter\decrypt.php on line 18

I tried to copy some lines in the encryption code but didn't work.

I also receive warning.

But I don't know if this is the cause. I also receive this on encryption.

> Warning: unpack(): 64-bit format codes are not available for 32-bit
>   versions of PHP in C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypter\decrypt.php on line 11
>
> Warning: unpack(): 64-bit format codes are not available for 32-bit
>   versions of PHP in C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypter\decrypt.php on line 12

**UPDATE**

- The warning is fixed by changing the pack() code from `P` to `V`.
- Upon changing the code the `$opslimit` has a value more than 0.

**DECRYPTION CODE**

```
$password = 'password';
$encrypted_file = 'tmp/inc.php';
$decrypted_file = 'tmp/inc.dec';

$fd_in = fopen($encrypted_file, 'rb');
$fd_out = fopen($decrypted_file, 'wb');

$alg = unpack('C', fread($fd_in, 1))[1];
$opslimit = unpack('V', fread($fd_in, 8))[1];
$memlimit = unpack('V', fread($fd_in, 8))[1];
$salt = fread($fd_in, SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES);

$header = fread($fd_in, SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETSTREAM_XCHACHA20POLY1305_HEADERBYTES);

$secret_key = sodium_crypto_pwhash(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETSTREAM_XCHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES,
                                   $password, $salt, $opslimit, $memlimit, $alg);

$stream = sodium_crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_init_pull($header, $secret_key);
do {
    $chunk = fread($fd_in, $chunk_size + SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETSTREAM_XCHACHA20POLY1305_ABYTES);
    $res = sodium_crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_pull($stream, $chunk);
    if ($res === FALSE) {
       break;
    }
    list($decrypted_chunk, $tag) = $res;
    fwrite($fd_out, $decrypted_chunk);
} while (!feof($fd_in) && $tag !== SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETSTREAM_XCHACHA20POLY1305_TAG_FINAL);
$ok = feof($fd_in);

fclose($fd_out);
fclose($fd_in);

if (!$ok) {
    die('Invalid/corrupted input');
}
```

This is the source code I use from the [libsodium example](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php#encrypt-a-file-using-a-key-derived-from-a-password).

Comment: The warning for `unpack` is probably the hint. You should try running it on 64-bit system. So the problem is more with trying to unpack 64-bit value on 32-bit system than with libsodium.

Comment: @Furgas, they're not connected base from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php I change it to 32 bit the error is still there.

Comment: Try to debug the bytes of `fread($fd_in, 8)` - maybe they are all zeroes.

Comment: @Furgas the value is encrypted something like this `�QO����`

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's in binary form. Instead of the line with `$opslimit =...` try `var_dump(bin2hex(fread($fd_in, 8)));`

Comment: @Furgas `string(16) "e9514ff1bfc9dcc8" ` the $opslimit has no value.

Comment: @Furgas I change everything to 'V' it displaying numbers now 2:alg -- 1957082864:ops--375774878:mem , but still the error is the same.

Comment: So it's a big number. You will have to test it on 64-bit system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was indeed not designed for 32 bit versions of PHP.

If you change `P` to `V`, you need to:

- Do it both in calls to `unpack()` and calls to `pack()`
- Change the number of bytes read/written from 8 to 4.

But the best thing to do would actually be trying to understand what the code does.

It stores the memory limit and iterations at the beginning of the file, so that these parameters can be recovered later when reading the file, without having to hard-code them.

`pack()` encodes a value in a fixed number of bytes. `unpack()` does the opposite.
`pack('P')` encodes a 64 bit value into 8 bytes. `unpack('P')` reads 8 bytes and converts them into a value.

If your environment doesn't support 64 bit values, pack/unpack to 4 bytes, but you then need to write 4 bytes, not 8. And read 4 bytes as well, not 8.